# VBScript delete characters from variable

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, command

I have this script

```
a=inputbox("Wat is het IP adres van de VPS?")
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C netsh interface ipv4 set address name=Wi-Fi source=static address="& a &" mask=255.255.254.0 gateway=185.18.148.1 & pause"
msgbox "IP adres: " +a
```

The user types his VPS IP address into the inputbox.
The gateway is VPS IP.1 (for example 8.8.8.1 when VPS IP is 8.8.8.8)

I would like to read the IP variable (a) and delete all characters right from the third dot

Example 1:
User types in 176.23.45.102
In this case, 102 should be deleted and the variable should be changed into 176.23.45.

Example 2:
User types in 17.23.45.4
In this case, 4 should be deleted and the variable should be changed into 17.23.45.

If not possible in VBScript, (Windows) command line/batch is also good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be a regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "(.*\.)\d+$"

addr = "176.23.45.102"
WScript.Echo re.Replace(addr, "$1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Split(), zap the 4th element, Join():

```
>> For Each s In Array("176.23.45.102", "7.23.45.4", "1.2.3.4")
>>     a = Split(s, ".")
>>     a(3) = ""
>>     WScript.Echo s, "=>", Join(a, ".")
>> Next
>>
176.23.45.102 => 176.23.45.
7.23.45.4 => 7.23.45.
1.2.3.4 => 1.2.3.
```

Inspired by @Ansgar - use a RegExp to zap the offending trailing digit(s):

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "\d+$"
>> WScript.Echo """" & r.Replace("1.2.3.4", "") & """"
>>
"1.2.3."
```